# How do I pagenate multiple gridviews on the same page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

I am creating an asp.net / C# application with 2 pages.

The JavaScript on `1stPage.aspx` will pass two parameters to the second page:

`2ndPage.aspx?Paramter1=abc&Paramter2=xyz`

`2ndPage.aspx` will fire a query to a SQL database and dynamically create a gridview.

I create 5 different gridviews on the same page dynamically with different IDs.
I want to pagenate gridview.

When I try to paginate, there is no change on the last 4 grids. Only pagination of first gridview is works properly.

I have tried to cache the dataview, but nothing seems to work.

C# CODE:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object Src, EventArgs E)
   {

   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
       string Param1= Page.Request.QueryString["Paramter1"];
       string Param1 = Page.Request.QueryString["Paramter2"];



       SqlDataAdapter cmdldata = new SqlDataAdapter("" + Param1 + " " + Param1, sqlconn);
       DataView dataview_ldata;




           GridView gv = new GridView();
           ph.Controls.Add(gv);
           gv.ID = "grid" + param1;
           gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
           gv.ShowFooter = false;
           gv.CellPadding = 2;
           gv.CellSpacing = 0;
           gv.Font.Size = 11;
           gv.EnableViewState = true;
           gv.AllowPaging = true;
           gv.PageSize = 10;
           gv.RowStyle.Wrap = false;
           gv.HeaderStyle.Wrap = false;

           gv.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(gv_PageIndexChanging);

           DataSet dsldata;
           dsldata = new DataSet();

           cmdldata.Fill(dsldata);

           dataview_ldata = dsldata.Tables[0].DefaultView;
           gv.DataSource = dataview_ldata;
           gv.DataBind();
           Cache["data"] = dataview_ldata;
           ph.DataBind();



   }//end of if IsPostBack


}//end of pageload


void gv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

   GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
   gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   gv.DataSource = (DataView)Cache["data"];
   gv.DataBind();
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:PlaceHolder id="ph" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please add the complete code

Comment: have you thought about using `ViewState` or `Session` and binding / persisting the data to a `DataTable`?

Comment: @DJKRAZE i have used DataTable instead of DataView for caching.But still pagination is not working

Comment: how many rows are being returned out of curiosity ? is it more than 10?

Comment: currently since I have set the Page size to 10,10 rows are being returned.And then I can see page numbers on the bottom of my grid on which when i click there is no response except the 1st gridview.(My tables contain more than 1000 records, so pagination is must for my Gridview)

Comment: From the research that I did,I have learnt that it is not possible to pagenate multiple gridviews on the same page.I have used Iframes to meet my requirement.